# Cannot use bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: css, django, datetimepicker

I want to include datetime picker in my template but having done this tutorial http://www.lisenme.com/date-time-picker-input-field-using-bootstrap/ my css and js files still cannot be found by django.

in template:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

and the error:

```
Not Found: /js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
Not Found: /css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
```

I downloaded the whole bootstrap-datetime picker, in my project tree created directories css and js and included files that the links refer to. Maybe here is the problem as I am not sure where to include the css and js files. I have tried two options so far: my_app/templates/my_app/css or my_app/templates/css. None of them was found by django

Comment: Did you iincluded them as statid files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Django does not automatically links templates to URL's, since for example a milicious user could aim to fetch template files, and then use these to introspect the system and find security weaknesses.

If you want the server to provide "static files", for example with [`staticfiles` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/).

In order to work with `staticfiles`, you need to include the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and specify the root URL for static files:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If you then store the files in the `static` directory of the app, like:

```
my_app/
    static/
        css/
            bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
        js/
            bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
```

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'%}"></script>
```

Note that it requires some extra steps to [deploy the static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#deployment).